# current user is not getting signed out

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using two mode of user authentication google and sign in with email and password. When I sign In or login with google and then pressed on sign Out the user signed out successfully but when  I sign In or login with email password and then pressed on sign Out the user it throws an PlateformException error.

Here is my signout methode

```
 Future<void> signOutUser() async {
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
```

I am using Bloc so here is my cubit class

```
class LogoutCubit extends Cubit<LogoutState> {
  LogoutCubit() : super(LogoutInitial());

  void logOut() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseRepo.instance.signOutUser();
      emit(LogoutSuccessState());
    }on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      emit(LogoutUnSuccessState(message: e.message));
    }
    on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      emit(LogoutUnSuccessState(message: e.message));
    }
  }
}
```

here is my home screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  User user;

  HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          BlocConsumer<LogoutCubit, LogoutState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is LogoutInitial)
                return Center(
                  child: Text("InitialState"),
                );
              else if (state is LogoutUnSuccessState)
                return Center(
                  child: Text(state.message),
                );
              return Container();
            },
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is LogoutSuccessState){
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginOrSignUpScreen()));
              }
            },
          ),
          Text(user.email),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<LogoutCubit>(context).logOut(),
              child: Text('Sign out'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my console when i click on logout button.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device CPH2001...
Restarted application in 2,912ms.
I/GED     (28464): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 15, oppidx_max 15, oppidx_min 0
W/DynamiteModule(28464): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(28464): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(28464): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/verse.filmmake(28464): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  (28464): uid=10286(com.kinoverse.filmmaker) AsyncTask #1 identical 1 line
I/verse.filmmake(28464): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(28464): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 287 native methods...
W/verse.filmmake(28464): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/verse.filmmake(28464): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/verse.filmmake(28464): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 36.514ms
I/ProviderInstaller(28464): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/ColorViewRootUtil(28464): nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 1256 mScreenHeight 2400 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=507.0, y[0]=1256.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1070309419, downTime=1070309419, deviceId=2, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
I/flutter (28464): PlatformException(status, Failed to disconnect., null, null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When signing out with `FirebaseAuth` all you need to do is to call `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()`. You don't need to sign out from Google seperately.

Comment: I have removed both google lines and it is throwing same error

Comment: Did you try `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` only?

Comment: I need one more clarification. I want to verify user before they sign up auth.sendvarificationemail() is not caughty what is best solution

Comment: I haven't really worked with email verification in Firebase, but I can suggest you to check out this video from Andy Julow: https://youtu.be/TLGe44gaEUM (it explains how to use email verification in Flutter with Firebase). There are also many other videos he did on Flutter and Firebase authentication. If my answer helped you please mark it as correct.